# How can I block the update on my SM-G930V?

Tags: android-versions, samsung-galaxy-s7, verizon

Note that my device is not rooted, and I have not downloaded the recent update yet

Comment: +1 because disabling com.wssyncmldm and com.sec.android.soagent via pm seems not sufficient according to XDA

Comment: @alecxs So it is impossible?

Comment: just wait for answer i am pretty sure it is possible. assuming you have already checked developer settings, there must be another solution